# Pylint doesnt execute

Tags: python

I have `test.py` file that I want to check using pylint in `checking.py` file with escaping refactor (R) and convention (C) messages. What I did wrong?

`test.py`

```
print("hello!")
```

`checking.py`

```
import pylint.lint
from pylint import epylint as lint
pylint_opts = ['--disable=R,C']
pylint.lint.Run(pylint_opts)
(pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr) = lint.py_run('test.py', return_std=True)
```

It returns me helping message assuming that I have typo when writing pylint options, but I wrote it ok as documentation says:

```
Messages control
-d <msg ids>, --disable=<msg ids>
                    Disable the message, report, category or checker with
                    the given id(s). You can either give multiple
                    identifiers separated by comma (,) or put this option
                    multiple times (only on the command line, not in the
                    configuration file where it should appear only once).
                    You can also use "--disable=all" to disable everything
                    first and then reenable specific checks. For example,
                    if you want to run only the similarities checker, you
                    can use "--disable=all --enable=similarities". If you
                    want to run only the classes checker, but have no
                    Warning level messages displayed, use "--disable=all
                    --enable=classes --disable=W".
There are 5 kind of message types :
* (C) convention, for programming standard violation
* (R) refactor, for bad code smell
* (W) warning, for python specific problems
* (E) error, for probable bugs in the code
* (F) fatal, if an error occurred which prevented pylint from doing
further processing.
```

Answer (score 0):

`epylint()` does its own [initialisation](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylint/epylint.py#L102) (calling `Run`) with `sys.argv`, ie. the arguments used when calling your checking.py

I guess you are just calling `python checking.py`, so `sys.argv[1:] == []`, which means in bash, you would be executing `pylint` (with any argument).

I think your solution is over-complicated. why don't you call `pylint --disable R,C test.py` on the command line ?

You could even write a [.pylintrc](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options) :

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=R,C
```

and just call `pylint test.py`

Comment: I have reason - because I want to automate it and want to understand how to run lint via code